# three.js 3d model orientation

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

As I didn't find an existing three.js quadcopter model, I'm trying to simulate one.
I created this "plus" symbol, but I'd like to orientate it as a "cross" symbol, i.e. rotated by +45° or -45° latitudinally

I don't mean this:

```
mesh.rotation.y+=THREE.Math.degToRad(45);
```

because I need to rotate it transversely like this:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/vcoumu83/25/

I mean that when I move the mouse on the X axis, the cross should rotate horizontally and not diagonally, on the dotted axis of the image

**UPDATE**
I'd like to achieve this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you want exactly. But if I add these lines, it looks like your image:

```
mesh.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
mesh.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad(45);
```

See updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcoumu83/30/

**Update:** You need to set `rotation.y` to the new rotate value.

```
mesh.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad(x);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcoumu83/46/

Comment: I explained bad, the problem is that when I move the mouse on the X axis, the cross should rotate horizontally and not diagonally, on the dotted axis of the image

Comment: sorry it isn't yet what I mean. looking at the image, imagine that the cross is a door that open towards you when you scroll horizontally. hope I've been clearer

Comment: So, the image is a top-down view and the cross should rotate around its mid point? https://jsfiddle.net/vcoumu83/48/

Answer (score 0):

While Brakebein answer is correct I think that maybe it would be simpler for you to just realign the geometry on the XY plane instead of the XZ, and then rotate it on the Z axis.

```
var x1=new THREE.BoxGeometry(25,1,1);
var x2=new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,25,1);
...
mesh.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(45);
```

Check lines 36-37 of this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcoumu83/37).